# Database requested by the login. The login failed Login Failed For WPF Standalone Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Windows WPF standalone application with EF data model on another running on another PC.
I have few changes on the source code, it works totally fine in the source code.
When I am trying to reinstall it on another PC using MSI Installer it throws the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
In the Log with the message

```
Cannot open database "C:\PHT\JCMS NG\DATABASE\JCMS_DB.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

This is the connection string I use for a release:

```
 <add name="DBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\Database\JCMS_DB.mdf&quot;;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Does anyone has this issue before?

Comment: Yes.  An MDF file can either be attached to a database or not attached.  You can't have both.  When attached you do not use localdb.  When localdb you do not use the Server Name.  You have both attached and localdb.  When attached the server owns the mdf file and cannot connect as local.  You also must have the MDF file physically on same machine as the server software.  You cannot map a drive to a remote machine and the use the driver letter for the mdf.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for answering me. If i get you write, you mean I need to change the data source of the connection string? I have The MDF file on the other PC.

Comment: If you are connecting between two machines the MDF must be attached and cannot be a localdb.  You then "MAY" end up not being able to connect with a username and password.  Then have to change from SQL Credentials to Windows Credentials.   Some networks block sending a password unencrypted.  So you have to use windows credentials.

Comment: Actually I have installed the database locally on the other PC and that was the purpose from the beginning.

Comment: 'I'm a Doubting Thomas".  I do not take error messages literally.  Seen too many cases where error messages are misinterpreted.  I think in this case "Login Failed" really means connection did not complete.  To see full reason I would use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database and then check log files with the explorer under Management.  You should see failure at same time PS was run with more details of user/group that was used.  Error will probably indicate the mdf file was not attached or could not be attached.

Comment: If MDF file is now local, then the windows permission of the file are wrong.  The username/password on the MDF would be properties on the file.  I'm not sure if the fixes on the following posting are correct : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851930/is-it-possible-to-change-the-user-account-of-the-localdb-instance-in-sql-server?force_isolation=truehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851930/is-it-possible-to-change-the-user-account-of-the-localdb-instance-in-sql-server?force_isolation=true  I'm confused because a localdb is not attached.

Comment: Maybe you need to attached the database to a server to fix username/password and then deattach the db so it is local.

Comment: what is the real error? are you debugging this line by line?